# Lagrange Multiplier Method using NLsolve.jl

Tags: julia

I would like to minimize a distance function `||dz - z||` under the constraint that `g(z) = 0`.
I wanted to use Lagrange Multipliers to solve this problem. Then I used `NLsolve.jl` to solve the non-linear equation that I end up with.

```
using NLsolve
using ForwardDiff

function ProjLagrange(dz, g::Function)
    λ_init = ones(size(g(dz...),1))
    initial_x = vcat(dz, λ_init)

    function gradL!(F, x)
        len_dz = length(dz)
        z = x[1:len_dz]
        λ = x[len_dz+1:end]
        
        F = Array{Float64}(undef, length(x))

        my_distance(z) = norm(dz - z)
        ∇f = z -> ForwardDiff.gradient(my_distance, z)
        F[1:len_dz] = ∇f(z) .- dot(λ, g(z...))

        if length(λ) == 1
            F[end] = g(z...) 
        else
            F[len_dz+1:end] = g(z) 
        end
    end
    nlsolve(gradL!, initial_x)
end


g_test(x1, x2, x3) = x1^2 + x2 - x2 + 5
z = [1000,1,1]

ProjLagrange(z, g_test)
```

But I always end up with `Zero: [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]` and `Convergence: false`.
Just so you know I have already solved the equation by using `Optim.jl` and minimizing the following function: `Proj(z) = b * sum(abs.(g(z))) + a * norm(dz - z)`.
But I would really like to know if this is possible with NLsolve. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Starting almost from scratch and wikipedia's [Lagrange multiplier page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) because it was good for me, the code below seemed to work. I added an `λ₀s` argument to the `ProjLagrange` function so that it can accept a vector of initial multiplier `λ` values (I saw you initialized them at `1.0` but I thought this was more generic). (Note this has not been optimized for performance!)

```
using NLsolve, ForwardDiff, LinearAlgebra
function ProjLagrange(x₀, λ₀s, gs, n_it)
    # distance function from x₀ and its gradients
    f(x) = norm(x - x₀)
    ∇f(x) = ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x)

    # gradients of the constraints
    ∇gs = [x -> ForwardDiff.gradient(g, x) for g in gs]

    # Form the auxiliary function and its gradients
    ℒ(x,λs) = f(x) - sum(λ * g(x) for (λ,g) in zip(λs,gs))
    ∂ℒ∂x(x,λs) = ∇f(x) - sum(λ * ∇g(x) for (λ,∇g) in zip(λs,∇gs))
    ∂ℒ∂λ(x,λs) = [g(x) for g in gs]
    
    # as a function of a single argument
    nx = length(x₀)
    ℒ(v) = ℒ(v[1:nx], v[nx+1:end])
    ∇ℒ(v) = vcat(∂ℒ∂x(v[1:nx], v[nx+1:end]), ∂ℒ∂λ(v[1:nx], v[nx+1:end]))

    # and solve
    v₀ = vcat(x₀, λ₀s)
    nlsolve(∇ℒ, v₀, iterations=n_it)
end

# test
gs_test = [x -> x[1]^2 + x[2] - x[3] + 5]
λ₀s_test = [1.0]
x₀_test = [1000.0, 1.0, 1.0]
n_it = 100

res = ProjLagrange(x₀_test, λ₀s_test, gs_test, n_it)
```

gives me

```
julia> res = ProjLagrange(x₀_test, λ₀s_test, gs_test, n_it)
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [1000.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 * Zero: [9.800027199717013, -49.52026655749088, 51.520266557490885, -0.050887973682118504]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 10
 * Convergence: true
 * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
 * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 11
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I altered your code as below (see my comments in there) and got the following output. It doesn't throw `NaN`s anymore, reduces the objective and converges. Does this differ from your `Optim.jl` results?

```
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [1000.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 * Zero: [9.80003, -49.5203, 51.5203, -0.050888]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 10
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
   * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 11
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 11
```

```
using NLsolve
using ForwardDiff
using LinearAlgebra: norm, dot
using Plots

function ProjLagrange(dz, g::Function, n_it)
    λ_init = ones(size(g(dz),1))
    initial_x = vcat(dz, λ_init)

    # These definitions can go outside as well
    len_dz = length(dz)
    my_distance = z -> norm(dz - z)
    ∇f = z -> ForwardDiff.gradient(my_distance, z)
    # In fact, this is probably the most vital difference w.r.t. your proposal.
    # We need the gradient of the constraints.
    ∇g = z -> ForwardDiff.gradient(g, z)
    
    function gradL!(F, x)
        z = x[1:len_dz]
        λ = x[len_dz+1:end]

        # `F` is memory allocated by NLsolve to store the residual of the
        # respective call of `gradL!` and hence doesn't need to be allocated
        # anew every time (or at all).
        F[1:len_dz] = ∇f(z) .- λ .* ∇g(z)
        F[len_dz+1:end] .= g(z)
    end

    return nlsolve(gradL!, initial_x, iterations=n_it, store_trace=true)
end

# Presumable here is something wrong: x2 - x2 is not very likely, also made it
# callable directly with an array argument
g_test = x -> x[1]^2 + x[2] - x[3] + 5
z = [1000,1,1]
n_it = 10000

res = ProjLagrange(z, g_test, n_it)

# Ugly reformatting here
trace = hcat([[state.iteration; state.fnorm; state.stepnorm] for state in res.trace.states]...)
plot(trace[1,:], trace[2,:], label="f(x) inf-norm", xlabel="steps")
```

[Evolution of inf-norm of f(x) over iteration steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzgFk.png)

[Edit: Adapted solution to incorporate correct gradient computation for g()]